# CKEditor data truncates when sending through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor version 4 and posting data from editor through ajax call however sometimes all the data post successfully and sometimes it just truncates it. As far I know the reason behind this is when editing the data it adds " " which cause this to truncate. Any help how to completely resolve this issue  ?

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('message');
     function checkSubmit() {

            for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances){
                CKEDITOR.instances['message'].updateElement();
            }

            var dataString = "action=<?php echo $_REQUEST['action']; ?>" + 
                "&id_user=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_user']; ?>" +
                "&sub_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['subject_id']; ?>" +
                "&subject_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['actual_subject_id']; ?>" +
                "&message="+ CKEDITOR.instances['message'].getData()+
                "&subject_name="+$("#subject").text() +
                "&occurence_name="+$("#occurency").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data/user-student-data.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    // close window
                    parent.closeDistributeModal( 1, "<?php echo $_REQUEST['action']; ?>", <?php echo $_REQUEST['id_user']; ?>,<?php echo $_REQUEST['subject_id']; ?> );
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very difficult way to gather up the data. Try this instead:

```
var data = {};
data.subject_id = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['actual_subject_id']; ?>';
data.id_user = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_user']; ?>';
data.action = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['action']; ?>';
data.sub_id = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['subject_id']; ?>';
data.occurence_name = $("#occurency").text();
data.subject_name = $("#subject").text();
data.message = CKEDITOR.instances['message'].getData();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data/user-student-data.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(returnedData) {
        // whatever you had here
    }
});
```

**Also**

```
// You can remove the for completely.. THIS:
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances){
    CKEDITOR.instances['message'].updateElement();
}

// Is the same as this (you don't use the instanceName variable at all)
CKEDITOR.instances['message'].updateElement();
```